# Converting String to Date in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I've read a few similar posts but I can't figure out where I'm still going wrong with the below:

```
let string = "2015-01-24T08:00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm"

print(formatter.date(from: string) ?? "Unknown date")
```

Output is always "*Unknown date*" (nil)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to check the formatter, Use this its really helpful https://nsdateformatter.com/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm"
```

Comment: That did it - thank you! Didn't see anything of the sort for the past hour so hopefully this helps someone else. Appreciate the quick response.